# Counting for probability problems with a sequence as probability space

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm making this post here because I can't comment on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645459/figuring-out-number-within-event-and-sample-space) one.

The problem in question is

> Suppose that a bag of scrabble tiles contains 5 Es, 4 As, 3 Ns and 2
> Bs. It is my turn and I draw 4 tiles from the bag without replacement.
> Assume that my draw is uniformly random. Let C be the event that I got
> two Es, one A, and one N.
>
> a.) Compute P(C) be imagining that the tiles are drawn one by one as an
> ordered sample.

The part i'm a little confused with is when the accepted answer says:

> As for trying to count how many of these outcomes correspond to having
> two E's, one A and one N... we can do so by first picking which of the
> four positions was occupied by an A, then which specific A it was for
> that position, which of the remaining positions was occupied by an N,
> then which specific N it was in that position, then for the left-most
> remaining space choose which specific E and finally pick which E for
> the final position. This gives a count of 4×4×3×3×5×4.

Towards the end when we handle the Es why don't we do 5x2x4x1 instead of just 5x4? At this point 2 slots are used up with A and N. We have 2 slots left for 2 Es. So in my mind we pick the first E (5 ways), then we pick 1 of 2 slots (2 ways) then we pick another E (4 ways) and then that last slot (1 way). This, however, doubles the result. Whats wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of equivalence: it doesn't matter where you put your E, the result is the same. So the sequence $E_1 E_2 A N$ is the same as the sequence $E_2 E_1 A N$, so you don't really have 2 choices of placing the E, since they would lead to the same result.

You would need to multiply by 2 if the sequences $E_1 E_2 A N$ and $E_2 E_1 A N$ would be different.

Comment: But our sample space considers them to be different right? So when we are trying to count the outcomes for the numerator E1E2AN and E2E1AN count separately to give 2 right?

Comment: You can model the problem however you want. You can consider an ordered sample space, where the order of the extraction matters, for example, or even a sample space where the exact letter matters (i.e. it matters if you pick A1 or A2). But this would lead to a larger sample space *and* a larger event, and they should cancel out and give the same result as if the sample space would consider them equivalent.